# How do I differentiate polynomials

Tags: calculus, derivatives

can someone show me how to differentiate stuff like x + 2 and

[image]

I've never did this before and I use the most god awful textbook imaginable.

Much thanks

Comment: It seems that you should pick up a different, better textbook if you do not understand the material that is being taught in your current one.

Comment: It is difficult to believe that even the worst calculus textbook available wouldn't be able to adequately show how to differentiate $x+2$. Are you even trying?

Comment: @Vincent I wish I was joking. When I search up the textbook we are forced to use, even in local education forums, I read nothing about how horrid it is. It is disgustingly bad and has only 5 lines to explain differentiation for the whole exercise. Worse, the 'worked' examples have no annotation to show the steps involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition the derivative $f'$ of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$$
Fix any real $h > 0$. Since the quotient
$$\dfrac{(x+h+2) - (x+2)}{h} = 1,$$
we have immediately
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(x+h+2) - (x+2)}{h} = 1,$$
which is exactly the derivative of the function $x \mapsto x+2$.

Comment: What does differentiation exactly mean? Why is the derivative of 2 = 0 ? In terms of multiplication, division etc..

Comment: @obligated At this level, I see two possible ways of defining *derivative*. One is the one implied by this answer, the other is axiomatic way (by means of rules, if you will). Which definition are you working with?

Comment: @GitGud The one implied yb the answer.

Comment: @obligated:   1) From geometrical meaning you may easily find from any calculus book, especially those for physics students. Analytic meaning is what we see above. 2) It is crucial to distinguish functional values from functions here! It is not that the derivative of $2$ is $0$, it is the derivative of the constant function $x \mapsto 2$ is $0$!

Comment: So with regards do you your question of why is the derivative of $f$, where $f(x)=2,$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$, can you write out the definition of $f'(x)$ for a given $x$?

Comment: If you dont like your text,try another one. Or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus#Differential_calculus to get started.

Comment: @obligated: Right, this analytic definition of differentiation is based upon the limit operation. So your question reduces to limit operation. Literally, the definition of differentiation given above means that, for a given real number $c$, a real number $f'(c)$ exists such that we can make the quotient arbitrarily close to $f'(c)$ by making $h$ sufficiently close to $0$.

Comment: Ah no problem! :)

Answer (score 4):

- In general the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives.
- The derivative of something of the form $ax^b$ is $abx^{b-1}$

Examples:
$$\frac{d(c)}{dx}=\frac{d(cx^0)}{dx}=c \cdot 0 x^{0-1}=0$$
Where $c$ is a constant.
$$\frac{d(x^2+3x+4)}{dx}=\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}+\frac{d(3x)}{dx}+\frac{d(4)}{dx}=2x^{2-1}+3\cdot 1 \cdot x^{1-1}+0=2x+3$$

I think you can continue with your exercises at that point

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)\pm g(x)]=\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]\pm \frac{d}{dx}[g(x)] $$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[ax^n]= a\frac{d}{dx}[x^n]= anx^{n-1} $$

Comment: Nice answer, although I'd delete the last line if I were you, as it follows immediately from line 2, with $n=0$ (and is therefore redundant).

Comment: @alexqwx, agreed. I'll edit now.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to know:

1. the derivative of a linear combination is the linear combination of the derivatives,

$$(x^6-5x^5-2x^4)'=(x^6)'-5(x^5)'-2(x^4)'$$

2. the derivative of a power is a power with exponent minus one, times the exponent.

$$(x^6)'=6x^5,$$
$$(x^5)'=5x^4,$$
$$(x^4)'=4x^3.$$

---

Why is it so ?

By definition, $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h.$$
For brevity, we will just write
$$\frac{f_h-f_0}h,$$
where the subscript $_h$ means "evaluated at $x+h$" and the subscript $_0$, "evaluated at $x$".

1. $$\frac{(af+bg)_h-(af+bg)_0}h=\frac{(af_h+bg_h)-(af_0+bg_0)}h=a\frac{f_h-f_0}h+b\frac{g_h-g_0}h,$$hence $(af+bg)'=af'+bg'$.
2. $$\frac{x^n_h-x^n_0}h=\frac{(x_h-x_0)(x^{n-1}_h+x^{n-2}_hx_0+x^{n-3}_hx^2_0+...x^{n-1}_0)}h=\\
   x^{n-1}_h+x^{n-2}_hx_0+x^{n-3}_hx^2_0+...x^{n-1}_0.$$
   This is obtained by factoring the binomial (you can check by executing the product and simplifying).

When $h$ tends to $0$, $x_h=x_0=x$, all $n$ terms become $x^{n-1}$, hence $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: This is massive overkill for differentiating polynomials. I don't think the OP was looking for a formal proof; just how to differentiate polynomials (i.e. the power rule).

Comment: There is no overkill at all. The operational rules are summarized in two easy sentences and one case solved.